# Auto Update Statistics and FULLSCAN in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, table-statistics

Is it possible to force `FULLSCAN` when statistics are updated *automatically* by SQL Server 2008 R2?

If not, is a planned `UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULLSCAN` the best way to keep statistics up-to-date?

note: The need for the `FULLSCAN` comes by proved suboptimal plan generation when using non-`FULLSCAN` statistics.

Comment: Tell us more about the sub-optimal plan. Perhaps share the actual query and schema with us too.

Comment: I don't really see what that has to do with the actual question... anyway, consider that the suboptimal plan used two clustered-index scans whereas in the optimal one they are not present (replaced by seeks on the same indexes). Just FYI, the two indexes were PKs of tables having 280M+ and 55M+ rows, respectively.

Comment: It *is* relevant An index scan is poor indexing or poor predicates Not statistics most likely

Comment: @gbn If your theory can explain why, immediately after manually updating the statistics and invalidating all execution plans, the average query duration dropped to 1/100th of the average duration we saw up to that moment then I could actually take into consideration John's request (but I won't be nevertheless able to share the queries and schemes, for they are proprietary)

Comment: Also, take into consideration that our findings have been verified by a Microsoft consultant (that was called in for unrelated DB problems).

Comment: @CAFxX: Ask an MS consultant then to answer your question

Comment: @gbn That's what I did on Friday, since no-one seemed to have a proper answer here on SO or on DBA. Unfortunately, his answer was that there's no way known to him to force `FULLSCAN` in the automatic statistics. We will probably have to fire off planned `UPDATE STATISTICS` multiple times per day, at least on the tables that change the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it looks like it's not possible (see my last comment on the question for details).